# Some JSON objects is undefined

Tags: json, node.js

So I'm working a bit with nodeJS and Steam API to try and make a trade bot
I need to know what items was recieved, but when I do I get

```
undefined
```

Here's the JSON:

```
    {  
   "partner":{  
      "universe":1,
      "type":1,
      "instance":1,
      "accountid":369917733
   },
   "id":"2112720622",
   "message":"No need to accept, just testing out a bot.",
   "state":3,
   "itemsToGive":[  

   ],
   "itemsToReceive":[  
      {  
         "appid":730,
         "contextid":"2",
         "assetid":"10168993563",
         "classid":"1989300153",
         "instanceid":"302028390",
         "amount":1,
         "missing":true,
         "icon_url":"IzMF03bi9WpSBq-S-ekoE33L-iLqGFHVaU25ZzQNQcXdB2ozio1RrlIWFK3UfvMYB8UsvjiMXojflsZalyxSh31CIyHz2GZ-KuFpPsrTzBG0qe6yD3n-ZDLdYXKOTVxqTudcPGjZrGLx5ujCF2nASeh-EF9XdfEAo2JLNZiKahtv0oMVu2u_0UdyEhk6f9BKZAarxm1OMLh9m3IWGBD1M58",
         "icon_url_large":"IzMF03bi9WpSBq-S-ekoE33L-iLqGFHVaU25ZzQNQcXdB2ozio1RrlIWFK3UfvMYB8UsvjiMXojflsZalyxSh31CIyHz2GZ-KuFpPsrTzBG0qe6yD3n-ZDLdEC3YDlltU-cLND7c92Hxt-SVFGqfFe54SgACdfcFoDJPP82AOBtrhdZZ-Ga9zhwzDhgvNMZJfACpx2EfJbQ1xDhPJM5amiekAf1NktA",
         "icon_drag_url":"",
         "name":"Sealed Graffiti | Still Happy (Desert Amber)",
         "market_hash_name":"Sealed Graffiti | Still Happy (Desert Amber)",
         "market_name":"Sealed Graffiti | Still Happy (Desert Amber)",
         "name_color":"D2D2D2",
         "background_color":"",
         "type":"Base Grade Graffiti",
         "tradable":true,
         "marketable":true,
         "commodity":true,
         "market_tradable_restriction":7,
         "fraudwarnings":[  

         ],
         "descriptions":[  
            {  
               "type":"html",
               "value":"This is a sealed container of a graffiti pattern. Once this graffiti pattern is unsealed, it will provide you with enough charges to apply the graffiti pattern <b>50</b> times to the in-game world.",
               "app_data":""
            },
            {  
               "type":"html",
               "value":" ",
               "app_data":""
            },
            {  
               "type":"html",
               "value":"",
               "color":"00a000",
               "app_data":{  
                  "limited":"1"
               }
            }
         ],
         "owner_descriptions":[  

         ],
         "actions":[  
            {  
               "name":"Inspect in Game...",
               "link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20S%owner_steamid%A%assetid%D9253357711394385702"
            }
         ],
         "market_actions":{  
            "0":{  
               "name":"Inspect in Game...",
               "link":"steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D9253357711394385702"
            }
         },
         "tags":[  
            {  
               "internal_name":"CSGO_Type_Spray",
               "name":"Graffiti",
               "category":"Type",
               "category_name":"Type"
            },
            {  
               "internal_name":"normal",
               "name":"Normal",
               "category":"Quality",
               "category_name":"Category"
            },
            {  
               "internal_name":"Rarity_Common",
               "name":"Base Grade",
               "category":"Rarity",
               "color":"b0c3d9",
               "category_name":"Quality"
            },
            {  
               "internal_name":"Tint5",
               "name":"Desert Amber",
               "category":"SprayColorCategory",
               "category_name":"Graffiti Color"
            }
         ],
         "id":"10168993563",
         "owner_actions":[  

         ],
         "market_marketable_restriction":0
      }
   ],
   "isOurOffer":true,
   "created":"2017-05-13T09:50:24.000Z",
   "updated":"2017-05-13T09:50:48.000Z",
   "expires":"2017-05-27T09:50:24.000Z",
   "tradeID":"1915564581201455085",
   "fromRealTimeTrade":false,
   "confirmationMethod":0,
   "escrowEnds":null,
   "rawJson":"{\n\t\"tradeofferid\": \"2112720622\",\n\t\"accountid_other\": 369917733,\n\t\"message\": \"No need to accept, just testing out a bot.\",\n\t\"expiration_time\": 1495878624,\n\t\"trade_offer_state\": 3,\n\t\"items_to_receive\": [\n\t\t{\n\t\t\t\"appid\": \"730\",\n\t\t\t\"contextid\": \"2\",\n\t\t\t\"assetid\": \"10168993563\",\n\t\t\t\"classid\": \"1989300153\",\n\t\t\t\"instanceid\": \"302028390\",\n\t\t\t\"amount\": \"1\",\n\t\t\t\"missing\": true\n\t\t}\n\t],\n\t\"is_our_offer\": true,\n\t\"time_created\": 1494669024,\n\t\"time_updated\": 1494669048,\n\t\"tradeid\": \"1915564581201455085\",\n\t\"from_real_time_trade\": false,\n\t\"escrow_end_date\": 0,\n\t\"confirmation_method\": 0\n}"
}
```

I can easily get partner, id, message, state, isOurOffer and all the time things, but when I try to get itemsToRecieve, it just throws undefined

The JSON is gathered through an event and the above is the exact JSON that I recieved

This is the event:

```
manager.on('sentOfferChanged', function(offer, oldState) {
    var state = offer.state;
    if(state == 3) {
        console.log("Offer " + offer.id + " was accepted");
        console.log("[Offer #" + offer.id + "] The following items was recieved: ");
        console.log(offer.itemsToReceive);
    }
});
```

Why would it do that for only one of the objects?

Comment: Not enough information. As JSON is valid and you said you were using streams, the only thing it comes to my mind is that the stream hasn't finished yet. You haven't yet received the whole stream.

Comment: show how your requesting. I guess async problem.

Comment: @JuanGG I never said I used streams

Comment: @FazalRasel Updated

Comment: Thank you for updating. Please post the code you are using to "get `itemsToRecieve`"

Comment: @Tom Updated. Thanks for your interest

Comment: At the beginning of your file please require `EventEmitter` like so: `const EventEmitter = require('events')`. Then before `console.log(offer.itemsToReceive)`, please insert `console.log(offer instanceof EventEmitter && typeof offer.read === 'function')` and post the result

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_before_E_except_after_C. Given that you seem to be confused about how to spell "received", I'd say there's a good chance your code may actually say `offer.itemstoRecieve`, in which case yes, it would be undefined.

Comment: @torazaburo It doesn't matter if it's spelled wrong if that's the actual name  of it (and also it's not misspelled)

Comment: @Tom The result is false

Comment: Even when JSONLint shows this as a valid JSON, it fails to parse through the `JSON.parse()` because of some invalid data in `rawJson`.

Comment: @FrejAlexanderNielsen your question starts with "So I'm working a bit with nodeJS and Steam API...". Anyway, open REPL and copy paste your JSON  assigning it to a var. var myJson = JSON.parse('{...}')  you can access to the value like this myJson.itemsToRecieve . It works. so that makes me thing you are doing something wrong. but if you don't give us more details about the implementation, we simply can not help you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use a for to log each item of itemToReceive.

Something like this:

```
manager.on('sentOfferChanged', function(offer, oldState) {
    var state = offer.state;
    if(state == 3) {
        console.log("Offer " + offer.id + " was accepted");
        console.log("[Offer #" + offer.id + "] The following items was recieved: ");

       for(var i in itemstoReceive)
         {
           var name = itemsToReceive[i].name;
           console.log(name);
             }}
});
```